# I am looking for a java library to check the JavaScript ES6 code statics such as code quality, ES6 lint status

Tags: javascript, java, ecmascript-6

I want to check the code syntaxes and code quality of ES6 JavaScript code piece. The project has been implemented using Java. So I'd like to know any existing Java libraries to identify the relevant needs.

This is not to identify the ES6 lint errors of the JavaScipt code written using eclipse or other Java IDEs

Comment: This question might better fit to https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/. Maybe you can borrow some code from https://eclipse.org/webtools/jsdt/ or or https://wiki.eclipse.org/Orion

Answer (score 0):

There is DeepScan. It seems like it is supports ES6.
https://deepscan.io/home/

Give it a try.